# Replace span content if image does not load

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Image and span tag. If the image doesn't load due to an error, I would like to remove the image element from the DOM and change the content of the span with id `loadErrorSpan` to say `"Access Denied. Please login."` otherwise it would be `"Loading...Please wait"`

```
<img src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.remove();" 
     alt="Some Image" width="100" height="120">
<br>
<span id="loadErrorSpan" style="font-family: sans-serif; 
   font-size:18px;text-align: center;color: #666;">Loading...Please wait</span>
```

I was able to remove the image on error, but not change the span content. How do I do this using JavaScript only. No Jquery or any other library should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `onerror` a specific handler, in that, replace the span content too

```js
function onImgLoadError(imgEl) {
  imgEl.remove()
  document.getElementById('loadErrorSpan').innerText = 'Loading failed'
}
```

```html
<img src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="onImgLoadError(this)" alt="Some Image" width="100" height="120">
<br>
<span id="loadErrorSpan" style="font-family: sans-serif; 
   font-size:18px;text-align: center;color: #666;">Loading...Please wait</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `span` element using `document.getElementById` and then change the content of `span` using `innerHTML`.

```js
function remove() {
  document.getElementById("loadErrorSpan").innerHTML = "Access Denied. Please login.";
}
```

```html
<img src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="remove();" 
     alt="Some Image" width="100" height="120">
<br>
<span id="loadErrorSpan" style="font-family: sans-serif; 
   font-size:18px;text-align: center;color: #666;">Loading...Please wait</span>
```